# Does a definite integral equal to the Möbius function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I've been studying infinite sums and came across the [Möbius function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and I was wondering if there exists a definite integral that represents it, or equivalently if there exists some $f(x,n)$ and $a, b$ such that

$$
\int_a^b f(x,n)dx = \mu(n).
$$

I have no idea how to begin to go about solving this problem, but through my basic workings, I have the suspicion that there may be no closed form that satisfies this equation.

Comment: This *in my opinion* is cheating (this is why I am leaving it as a mere comment), but using the usual Dirichlet generating function for the Möbius function along with the usual formula for the coefficients of a Dirichlet series (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/329980)), we have: $$\mu(n)=n^{\sigma} \lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T} \frac{n^{it}}{\zeta(\sigma+it)}\mathrm dt$$ for $\sigma > 1$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you stated it you can define $f(x,n)$ is many ways to generate any sequence.

A more interesting answer is that what we want is a generating function of the sequence $\mu(n)$, and that the natural ones are $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{-s}$$ The partial sums admitting explicit formulas in term of the non-trivial zeros $$f(s)=\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) n^{-s}$$ The inverse Mellin transform of $\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ (again admitting an explicit formula) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) e^{-nx}$$ 
Its periodic versions
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} e^{inx}$$ 
and the weird Riesz function $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} e^{-x/n^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{\zeta(2+2k)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} \frac{1}{ \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2\pi)^{2k} B_{2k}}{(2k)!}}$$
All the other *useful* generating functions of $\mu(n)$ are more or less directly related to one of them.

Answer (score 12):

Sure. Fix any $a<b$, and put $f(x,n)=\tfrac{1}{b-a}\mu(n)$ (independent of $x$).

Comment: well that was trivial!

Answer (score 3):

If we allow bending the rules a bit to study the Mertens function
$$M(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\mu(x)$$
and improper integral representations, then there's the Perron formula
$$M(x)=\lim_{\sigma\to 1^+}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\pi}\frac{x^{\sigma+\mathrm{i}t}}{(\sigma+\mathrm{i}t)\zeta(\sigma+\mathrm{i}t)}\text{.}$$